# How to create shell aliases in Emacs [GUI] in Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, gui-emacs, aliases

In Linux this can be done by something like:

`alias cdwww="cd /srv/www"`

In Windows there is an equivalent command called `DOSKEY`, used for example like this:

`doskey ls=dir $*`

The above works perfectly in Windows' built-in CMD but not in Emacs shell. Emacs simply ignores it and throws an error:

`'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Any idea how to create aliases in Emacs for Windows?

Comment: Arguably, if you start creating aliases resembling Unix commands, it may be easier for you to just install bash and co through Cygwin.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, thank you that is indeed the best way to go. I have installed `Cgwin` and ran `Emacs` but I have a strange issue: every time I hit `enter` in shell I get a line like this: `^[]0;~^G`, what is that? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, not sure what could that be… While searching around I see that [apparently lots of people successfully use Emacs + Cygwin combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235254/how-can-i-run-cygwin-bash-shell-from-within-emacs), so offhand no idea why could that be happening for you.

Comment: If you have Windows 10, I can recommend WSL (you may have considered and rejected this already).
In Cygwin, what do you see when you "echo $PROMPT"? If you get that everytime you hit enter, it may be a prompt with some escape codes embedded.